# Jest coverage reporting on all committed files in create-react-app

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

Having difficulty with generating Jest coverage reports for all committed files in my create-react-app.

Initially, code coverage was generating as expected, however something has changed in my environment, and now only files changed since the last commit are showing coverage.

I see there are many other posts about this issue, however I am unable to resolve it myself.

package.json:

```
{...
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testMatch": [ "**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ],
        "coverageReporters": ["json","html","lcov", "text"]
    }
...}
```

Project structure:

```
|
+--node_modules
+--src
    |
    + __tests__
    + App.js
- package.json
```

Running command `npm test -- --coverage` produces the following output:

```
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Comment: You're running it in watch mode, it can't report coverage for tests it didn't run. Try e.g. `CI=true npm test -- --coverage`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `CI` environment variable controls other functions besides watch mode, and they may desire watch mode.

Comment: @evelynhathaway that's true, the point was to demonstrate that coverage *is* generated for the tests that are run.

Answer (score 4):

You are in watch mode, which [has a known issue when running coverage on a subset of files](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7331). Try using `--watchAll` so that all tests run and coverage can be generated.

```
npm test -- --coverage --watchAll
```

I like to make a special npm run-script in my `package.json` called `coverage` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this script `react-scripts test --coverage` with `a` included in order to run all tests.

Like this: `react-scripts test --coverage a`